# Badge congratulations box is too large

Tags: bug, design

The box that contains the "Congratulations" message for a newly awarded badge is too large. The button with "Track the next one" is nearly hidden completely:

[image]

Observed on FireFox 62.0

Comment: Observed like this (and seemingly different from the proposed duplicate) on Opera (55.0), too.